# can't get notification from firebase - swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't get any push Notidication.

I tried to send a notification from Firebase console, to all the users of the app.

The Console says that the notification been sent to one device (my device), but I do not get anything on my iPhone.

I'm running this code at AppDelegate.swift:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  mt
//
//  Created by ES on 15.6.2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 ES. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        registerForPushNotifications()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        let dict = userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
        let title = dict["alert"]
        print ("@", title!)
    }


    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")

            guard granted else { return }

            let viewAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "addToCal",
                                                  title: "New date available!",
                                                  options: [.foreground])

            let newsCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "NEW_SESSION",
                                                      actions: [viewAction],
                                                      intentIdentifiers: [],
                                                      options: [])
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([newsCategory])
            self.getNotificationSettings()
        }
    }

    func getNotificationSettings() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
            return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
        }

        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register: \(error)")
    }


}
```

(I got the Token, so I think that my app have the permission to get notifications)

Comment: are you testing from a simulator?

Comment: testing on my iPhone.